# Does the ball hitting the sidewall reset the bounce?

Tags: rules, squash

The ball hits the front wall then takes a bounce and then hits the sidewall. Is the ball allowed to take another bounce before being returned?

Essentially the concept is that after hitting a wall the counter of having just 1 bounce would reset allowing another bounce.

Answer (score 6):

According to the rules on [World Squash](http://www.worldsquash.org/ws/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/131023_Rules-of-Singles-Squash-2014.pdf) site

> A return is good if the ball:
>
> **6.2.1 is struck correctly before it has bounced twice on the floor**; and
>
> 6.2.2 without hitting either player, or their clothing or racket, hits the front wall,
>   either directly or after hitting any other wall(s), above the tin and below
>   the out-line, without having first bounced on the floor; and
>
> 6.2.3 rebounds from the front wall without touching the tin; and
>
> 6.2.4 is not out.

So, regardless if it hits the side or back wall, the ball can only bounce at most once to keep the rally going. 
The rules only mention the requirement of hitting the front wall above the tin. the ball can strike any other wall at anytime provided the ball only has at most bounced once.

Answer (score 1):

On its way to the front wall's legal zone (Area between top most line and the tin area), The ball must not bounce off floor once hit by your racquet.
However, enroute to the front wall it is allowed to "bounce off" the other three walls. Similarly, once it hits the front wall, it is allowed to "bounce off" the other 3 walls an infinite number of times - unlikely- however may only bounce on the floor once at most (or hit on the volley before it even bounces off floor) before the other player hits the return shot. Again this return shot is not allowed to bounce on the floor enroute to the front wall - however, it may bounce off any number of the other three walls on its way to the front wall. HTH...

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

As you clearly know, after multiple wall bounces, the ball remains in play. But only **one** floor bounce is allowed. If the ball hits the ground a second time, the rally is won/lost—regardless of how many times the walls have been hit.